# Lubuntu 16.10 trackpad not responsive at all

Tags: hardware, touchpad, lubuntu

I've searched high and low for a solution to this, I've tried [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/543669/why-is-my-trackpad-not-working-in-lubuntu-14-10) and [this](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2322413).

Along with what seems like a plethora of others.

When I run xinput I get the following output

```
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Razer Razer DeathAdder Chroma             id=12   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Razer Razer DeathAdder Chroma             id=13   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Sleep Button                              id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Sleep Button                              id=11   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Razer Razer DeathAdder Chroma             id=14   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ HD WebCam                                 id=15   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=16   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

My mouse, according to this, is detected twice.  Making me wonder if the system is somehow confusing it with touchpad.

I really need this as I use my laptop away from desks literally on my lap all the time and on top of that I need to develop on Linux.

Other than a fresh install of a different distro, can anyone assist in getting it to work?